# relationship between a great circle arc and a latitude circle arc at a given latitude

Tags: geometry, spheres, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

My spherical geometry is a bit rusty but looking at the figure below:

[image]

... my intuition tells me that angles $\phi$ and $\theta$ (measured in radians) are connected with the following equation:

$\phi = \theta*cos(\delta)$

... where $\delta$ is the angle corresponding to the green arc.
At least the above holds true for the special cases $\delta=0$ and $\delta=\pi/2$. Does the above equation hold true in general and what is the terminology that describes the various angles and circles I've drawn?

## update on terminology

It is now clear that the angles can be more properly described as follows:

- angle $\theta$ is the arc between points $A'$ and $B'$ on a latitude circle at latitude $\delta$ (see the drawing on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2950640/50256) which makes this point clear)
- angle $\phi$ is the arc between points $A'$ and $B'$ on a great circle

Comment: It seems about right. Depends on whether the angle changes linearly or sinusoidally. I would guess sinusoidally but I'd have to do geometry to check

Comment: Careful........ You've labelled $\phi$ as if it were the angle between two central rays, but then corresponding to that central angle you have connected the two points where those rays hit the sphere by a latitude circle. Although it's true that the length of a great circle arc is equal to the corresponding central angle (in radians, assuming radius $=1$), it is NOT TRUE that the length of a latitude circle is equal to the corresponding central angle.

Comment: @LeeMosher $\phi$ is the angle between the two central rays; that's the only thing that interests me. I am not sure I fully comprehend the point you are making.

Comment: If the length along the latitude circle is not of concern, in particular if there is no risk of confusing $\phi$ with the length of that latitude segment, then fine.

Comment: @LeeMosher thanks; I now see your point. I am denoting with $\phi$ the angle between the rays `OA'` and `OB'` that reside on the plane defined by points `O`, `A'` and `B'`. I.e. $\phi$ is an ordinary two-dimensional Euclidean geometry angle.

Comment: @LeeMosher moreover, what you refer to as "the length of the latitude segment" is exactly the same whether we talk about `A'B'` or `AB` and is in fact the angle $\theta$. What I am looking for is a way to express $\theta$ in terms of $\phi$ and $\delta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance between the endpoints is scaled down like the circle radius by a factor of $\cos\delta$. However, that rather makes
$$ \sin \frac\phi2=\cos\delta\sin \frac\theta2.$$

Comment: I am trying to derive $\theta$ given $\phi$ and $\delta$. How do I do that using your formula? My feeling is that the formula I give is accurate, at least for small values of $\phi$ and $\theta$

Comment: I just figured why this holds; will try to upload a diagram

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer by Hagen von Eitzen is correct.
This is just to supply a proof.
The below proof uses only the basic trigonometric definitions of $cos$ and $sin$ as well as a very elementary theorem about isosceles triangles.

In the figure below points $A'$ and $B'$ have been renamed to $A$ and $B$ and the points $A$ and $B$ in the original drawing have been omitted as they are not necessary for the proof. In particular the angle $\theta$ of the original drawing (that was defined using points on the great circle) is the same as the angle $\theta$ of the new drawing that is defined using points on the latitude circle.

Refer to the figure below and observe the following elements:

- a great circle with center $O$ (therefore $O$ is also the center of the sphere)
- a latitude circle at latitude $\delta$ with center $O'$
- the straight line segment $AB$ (a line segment, not an arc) with point $\Gamma$ as its midpoint
- three right angles shaded grey and outlined red
- the right triangle $AO'O$ with the right angle being the one at point $O'$
- the right triangle $O'\Gamma{}A$ (which resides on the plane defined by the latitude circle) with the right angle being the one at point $\Gamma$
- the right triangle $A\Gamma{}O$ with the right angle being the one at point $\Gamma$
- angle $\phi$ is the angle $AOB$, the angle $AO\Gamma{}$ being exactly $\phi/2$
- angle $\theta$ is the angle $AO'B$, the angle $AO'\Gamma{}$ being exactly $\theta/2$

Observe that the angle $OAO'$ is identical to the angle $\delta$ and that $OA$ is a ray of the sphere, so we can write $OA=R$

[image]

We have the following equations:

1. $O'A = R\cdot{}cos(\delta)$ ; since $OA$ is the hypotenuse and equal to $R$, and since $OAO'=\delta$ as already noted
2. $A\Gamma{}=O'A\cdot{}sin(\theta/2)$

From $1$ and $2$ we obtain:

3. $A\Gamma{}=R\cdot{}cos(\delta)\cdot{}sin(\theta/2)$

We also have (from the right triangle $A\Gamma{}O$):

4. $A\Gamma{}=R\cdot{}sin(\phi/2)$ ; since $OA$ is the hypotenuse and equal to $R$

From $3$ and $4$ we have:

$$sin(\frac\phi2)=cos(\delta)\cdot{}sin(\frac\theta2) $$

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

My attempt of a proof:

In any circle, with center O, radius r, points A and B on the circumference and angle AOB = $\alpha$, the straight segment from A to B is :
$AB_{straight}^2 = 2 r^2 \times (1-cos(\alpha))$ (1)

This is a straight application of the cosine theorem.

We also know for any angle $\alpha$ that 
$cos(\alpha) = 1-2 sin^2 (\frac{\alpha}{2})$ (2)

By combining (1), (2) we get :
$AB_{straight}^2 = 4 r^2 \times sin^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})$ (3)

Apply (3) twice on the segment $A'B'$ from the original diagram by Marcus Junius Brutus :

- once for the great circle with $r=R$ and $\alpha = \phi$
- once for the latitude circle with $r=R \times cos(\delta)$ and $\alpha=\theta$

That gives 
$4 R^2 \times sin^2(\frac{\phi}{2})$ = $4 (R \times cos(\delta))^2 \times sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})$

which simplifies to
$sin(\frac{\phi}{2}) = cos(\delta) \times sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$